# Why is this not reading my file?

Tags: java, exception

I'm having problems getting my program to read an input file from the same directory.
code is in Main, included the whole just incase i have done something outside of main that is causing this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Final
{
    public static int readData(BusinessDirectory [] array, Scanner input,Scanner inputFile)
    {
        int lastChar = 0;
        int count =0;
        int dirChoice = 0;

        int area,
            exchange,
            number,
            extension;
        String name;


        while(inputFile.hasNextLine() && count < array.length)
        {

            String Og = inputFile.nextLine();
            lastChar = (Og.length()-1);
            dirChoice = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(0,1));
            if(dirChoice == 1)
            {
                area = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(2,5));
                exchange = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(6,9));
                number = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(10,14));
                name = Og.substring(15,lastChar);
                array[count].DirectorySet(area, exchange, number, name);

            }

            if(dirChoice == 2)
            {
                area = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(2,5));
                exchange = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(6,9));
                number = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(10,14));
                extension = Integer.parseInt(Og.substring(15,19));
                name = Og.substring(20,lastChar);
                array[count].BusinessDirectorySet(area, exchange, number, extension, name);
            }
        }
        return count;
        }

    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        String infile;
        int count=0;;

        //Directory[]array = new Directory[25];
        BusinessDirectory[]array = new BusinessDirectory[25];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the input file: ");
            infile = in.next();


        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File(infile);
            Scanner fin = new Scanner(inputFile);
            readData(array, in, fin);
            System.out.println(BusinessDirectory.getName());
        //  System.out.println("test");
            //count = readData(array,in,inputFile);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("\"" + infile + "\" not found. Program will terminate.");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        }
    }
```

it always throws the Exception from the Catch.
("test.txt" not found. Program will terminate.)

e.printStackTrace();
gets me

```
What is the input file: test.txt
java.lang.NullPointerException
"test.txt" not found. Program will terminate.
    at Final.readData(Final.java:36)
    at Final.main(Final.java:69)
```

Error seems to be in my Directory Class

```
public class Directory 
{
    //data members
    static int Area;
    static int Exchange;
    static int Number;
    static String Name;
    static int cause;

    public Directory()
    {
        Area = 999;
        Exchange = 999;
        Number = 9999;
        Name = "";
        cause = 0;
    }
    public Directory(int area, int exchange, int number, String name)
    {
        DirectorySet(number, number, number, name);
    }

    public void DirectorySet(int area, int exchange, int number, String name)
    {
        try
        {
            if(area >= 200 && area <= 999 && area != 911)
            {
                if(exchange >= 200 && exchange <= 999 && exchange !=911)
                {
                    if(number >= 0 && number <= 9999)
                    {
                        Area = area;
                        Exchange = exchange;
                        Number = number;
                        Name = name;
                    }else
                        {
                        cause = 1;
                        MyOwnException error = new MyOwnException();
                        MyOwnException.Message = error.setMessage(cause);
                        throw error;
                        }
                    }else if(exchange == 911 || area == 911)
                        { 
                        cause = 4;
                        MyOwnException error = new MyOwnException();
                        MyOwnException.Message = error.setMessage(cause);
                        throw error;
                        }

                cause = 2;
                MyOwnException error = new MyOwnException();
                MyOwnException.Message = error.setMessage(cause);
                throw error;            
                }else
                    {
                    cause = 3;
                    MyOwnException error = new MyOwnException();
                    MyOwnException.Message = error.setMessage(cause);
                    throw error;
                    }
            }
        catch(MyOwnException error)
        {
            System.out.println(toString());
            System.out.println(MyOwnException.Message);
            //System.out.println(Directory.toString());
        }


    }

    public void toString(int area, int exchange, int number, String name)
    {
        System.out.println(name + " (" + area + ") " + exchange + " -" + number);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return (Name + " (" + Area + ") " + Exchange + " -" + Number);
    }
    public static String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public static int getArea()
    {
        return Area;
    }

    public static int getExchange()
    {
        return Exchange;
    }

    public static int getNumber()
    {
        return Number;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public void setArea(int area)
    {
        Area = area;
    }
    public void setExchange(int exchange)
    {
        Exchange = exchange;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }

}
```

..

```
Final.readData(Final.java:37)
array[count].DirectorySet(area, exchange, number, name);

Final.main(Final.java:73)
readData(array, fin);
```

Comment: **What** exception is being thrown? From where exactly? What don't you understand about the exception message?

Comment: what exception is thrown? and where?

Comment: I think you are not providing file path properly.

Comment: Note that it's not because it throws an exception that it's automatically `FileNotFoundException`, you should *at least* print `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for clearer understanding of the problem

Comment: Change `catch(Exception e)
        {` to `catch(Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: In the catch block, don't terminate the program, rather print the stacktrace. else print the exception. `System.out.println(e);` or `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: You can do two catches. One catch like you have it now, but change the println to `e.printStackTrace()`. The second catch can be `catch(FileNotFoundException ex)`.

Comment: @asifsid  The stack trace gives more information than either of `e.getMessage()` **or** `System.out.println(e);`!

Comment: @AndrewThompson True! but just to tell him that rather just exiting he can do any of the two (or three)

Comment: @jontejj  Not only is that suggestion sub-standard, but it has already been made!

Comment: I only meant it as a debugging helper. Removed the comment:)

Comment: please use common java convenctions before posting here, i.e. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` seems to be thrown at this line :

```
array[count].DirectorySet(area, exchange, number, name);
```

The problem is that you correctly created the `array` this way :

```
BusinessDirectory[]array = new BusinessDirectory[25];
```

But that creates only the space for 25 object pointers, that doesn't actually creates 25 objects.

You have to create each object one by one, in your case you should probably do this :

```
array[count] = new Directory(area, exchange, number, name);
```

instead of this :

```
array[count].DirectorySet(area, exchange, number, name);
```

Also you don't seem to increment `count` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File inputFile = new File(infile);
System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

This will give you a hint about your working directory and you can fix your input (absolute or relative paths)

Also it is recommended that if you're not sure about the relative location and do not wish to use absolute paths, use the `File.exists()` API to make a decision within your code.